# How does `operator delete` deallocate the memory block for node of LinkedList

Tags: c++

```
struct node
{
    node(int _value, node* _next) : value(_value), next(_next) {}

    int   value;
    node* next;
};

node *p = new node(10, NULL);
delete p;
```

Based on my understanding, `operator delete` will first call the destructor of `node`, then deallocate the raw memory block originally allocated for `p`.

Since `struct node` doesn't provide a customized destructor, the compiler will provide a default one.

**Question1**>what does the default destructor look like?
For example,

```
node::~node()
{
  next = NULL;
}
```

**Question2**>should we define a destructor for `struct node` or not?
I assume that we don't have to explicitly provide such a destructor. The reason is that the member variable `next` doesn't own the pointed resource and it behaves as a `weak_ptr`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds correct to me.

Because `struct node` is a "[Plain Old Datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c)" the compiler won't actually create any destructor code at all, there's no need to specially destruct ints or pointers.

Even for non-POD types, the compiler default destructor will just take the form:

```
~node() { }
```

Individual members will still have their destructors called, but if you didn't allocate any non-automatic resources, you generally don't need to provide a destructor. There are situations where you might, but they're somewhat special purpose.

You may want to refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) on the rule of three.